# str_replace "array" is not removing commas

Tags: php

I am trying to remove both percents (%) and commas (,) and it seems to only remove the percents.

```
function votesremaining($totalvotes, $firstplace, $currentplace) {
    $search = array('%', ',');
    $replace = array('', '');
    $formula = round(str_replace($search,$replace,$totalvotes * ((($firstplace+1) - $currentplace) / 100)));
    return $formula;
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Mind showing what some input looks like? (i.e `$totalvotes, $firstplace, $currentplace`..)

Comment: are totalvotes, firstvotes and current place numbers? why would you have a % or a ,? they seem to be integers

Comment: Read the [DOCs](https://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Input is entered as a percent for $firstplace & $currentplace. $totalvotes are often entered with commas, which I need to strip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably messed up the parenthesis. One missing right after $totalvotes.

```
$formula = round(str_replace($search,$replace,$totalvotes) * ((($firstplace+1) - $currentplace) / 100));
```

However, I'm not too sure what you are expecting with that one statement. The product will probably not work anyway.

Maybe you meant to split the string in an array and then multiply each entry the product you have here?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

---

Update:

I see that you posted a comment pretty much saying that `$totalvotes` will just be one number but possibly with commas and percent characters. So... no preg_split() needed, indeed!

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing after doing the math - the normal use case would be to do the replacing before the math.

I don't really know what your function's input is, but it should be something like this:

```
function votesremaining($totalvotes, $firstplace, $currentplace) {
    $search = array('%', ',');
    $replace = array('', '');
    $totalvotes = str_replace($search, $replace, $totalvotes);
    $firstplace = str_replace($search, $replace, $firstplace);
    $currentplace = str_replace($search, $replace, $currentplace);
    $formula = round($totalvotes * (($firstplace+1) - $currentplace) / 100);
    return $formula;
```

}